# Password regex not working in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to run the below code to validate a password string against my regex. But it's always returning false. What am I doing wrong ?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
     val PASSWORD_REGEX = """^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%!\-_?&])(?=\\S+$).{8,}""".toRegex()
    val password:String = "Align@123"
    println(PASSWORD_REGEX.matches(password))
}
```

Comment: You have '(?=\\S+$)' group which as I know checks \S at the end of a string. Delete this group and your regex should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using raw strings but are escaping the last `\S` which is causing a literal match of `\S`. If I remove the extra backslash, your test case works for me. And as others have stated, you might be able to remove that stanza entirely.

So this...

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%!\-_?&])(?=\\S+$).{8,} 
                                                       ^
                                                       |
                                               Remove -+
```

Becomes this

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%!\-_?&])(?=\S+$).{8,}
```

I used [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to help me, which seems to be a nice way to turn regex into English.

Comment: Awesome. Spot on